# Option Menu stays empty white in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, menu

I just tried to add an option menu to my app, but it's not showing any content.

Here's my XML:

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/item1" 
        android:title="Test1"/>
    
    <item android:id="@+id/item2" 
        android:title="Test2"/>
        
    <item android:id="@+id/item3" 
        android:title="Test3" 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"/>

</menu>
```

Path is `res/menu/menu.xml`

That's my code in the main activity:

```java
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    return true;
}
```

I can open the menu and it shows three white squares. I can click on them and the menu closes.

I tried changing the text color via `android:textColor` and the background color via `android:color`, but this didn't work either.

Edit: It's working if I use `menu.add(...)`, but I actually do prefer using the XML resource...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `<menu xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">` to `<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

Comment: Omg, thank you! So much about copy&paste from some website's examples... xD